# I have lost my MOTO E

Tags: google-play-store, google

My device has stolen by someone,,, i need to block the Device as completely useless
Find the following IMEI Details,

IMEI No.: 359299053253550
          359899053253568

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Device Manager from the web to try finding your device. It can "call" and maybe lock & wipe your device, too.

Android Device Manager: https://www.google.de/android/devicemanager